# making directory in C in linux

Tags: c, linux

I've a c program which create and works with files. how can tell  the prgram to read a file from a subdirectory and save another in 2 sub direct, here what I've tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main (){
    char fileName1[10];
    char fileName2[10];
    FILE *in=NULL,*out=NULL;
    // making directory , input directotry exist as subdir in Program  folder  
    mkdir("ouput", 777);
    fileName1="//input//test";
    fileName ="//output//out1";
    ........................  
}
```

after trying toopen the files nothing happens, and the directoty hasn't been created. any hint how can I do that ! 
**UPDATE**
the directory now is created but the file in it No ?

**UPDATE**
MY fileName has any index so here is what I'm exactly doing :

```
while((access(fileName,F_OK)!=-1)){ // check if the file  already exist
    sprintf(fileName,"./output/sample%d",index++);  
}
```

the making of the directory of the directory work but making the file in dir is the problem the program just crashes

Comment: Check the return value of mkdir for created or not?

Comment: i think, yours is related to permission problem.

Comment: `777` should be `0777`. Permissions are in octal, not in decimal.

Comment: now the the directory is created but  the program doesn't write or create the file in it ?

Comment: @Engine try like this,   fp = fopen ("./output/test.txt", "w");

Comment: that's what I'm doing

Comment: Is it "ouput" or "output" you are trying to `mkdir`?

Comment: what? sorry I don't get what you mean !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fileName1="./output/sample.txt";
```

consider here **output** is directory name. Relative path also can be specified to open file.

Comment: thanks for your answer , but I get segmentation fault (core dumped) error !

Comment: it works I dont exactly what was the problem you answer helped solving this , thanks !

Answer (score 1):

...

```
char fileName1[10];
char fileName2[10];
```

...
    mkdir("ouput", 777);

as pointed out in the comments, that should be 0777, and you *really* should check the return value.

```
fileName1="//input//test";
```

filename1 is currently an array of characters, but you are now pointing it to a string, which is probably in read-only memory. You should try compiling with -Wall. Moreover, this file is apparently  expected to live in the root of your file system.

```
fileName ="//output//out1";
```

And again. Probably you want to declare these as `char const *` or copy the string into the buffer (which needs to be a lot larger).

Answer (score 0):

in order to create a directory from c program you have to specify an umask. a quote from [here](http://blog.tremend.ro/2008/10/06/create-directories-in-c-using-mkdir-with-proper-permissions/):

> When you create a new file or directory, some of its permissions are
>   restricted and cannot be set. Each process has a set of restrictions
>   called the umask, and you must use the umask system call to disable or
>   enable those restrictions.

so if you want no restrictions on permissions to that directory, you specify umask to 0. later, you have to set umask to the previous value.


a full program that creates directory in current path and two files within created dir:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    mode_t process_mask = umask(0);
    mkdir("test",0777);
    umask(process_mask);
    char filename[50] = "./test/file1";
    char filename2[50] = "./test/file2";

    FILE* file1;
    FILE* file2;
    file1 = fopen(filename, "w");
    file2 = fopen(filename2, "w");
    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);
    return 0;
}
```